# Name a view or table as todays date YYYY-MM-DD or similar

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I do a simple:

```
Select * into    XXXXXX     from dbo.BSAK
```

with the XXXXXX table name is in the format  FILE_2017-03-29 (todays date)

Basically I will be using either this select into or a 'create view as' to store the data for tables in a job and name it as that date... If I can do it for the simple select into I will apply it to the others.

Comment: You have a poor data design if you have tables with dates in the name.  Instead of creating a new table each day, your process should be inserting into an existing table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I understand. This is more just to create tables/views to be used as backups for like a management report... Not really part of the actual database...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql...

```
declare @sql varchar(max) 
select @sql = concat('Select * into ' , '[File_',convert(date,getdate()), '] from dbo.bsak ')
Exec (@sql)
```

But its bad design to create table daily...